# Enabling a disabled field using javascript executor for selenium webdriver ruby binding script

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing following Ruby code in Selenium Webdriver script to enable a disabled field on UI through Javascript executor.

```
browser.execute_script("browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/input'.disabled = false")
```

But facing,

`handleEvaluateEvent': syntax error (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)

What could be wrong with my syntax?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks!
Abhishek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem with the line:

```
browser.execute_script("browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/input'.disabled = false")
```

Is that it is trying to execute selenium-webdriver code instead javascript - ie `browser.find_element` is not javascript.

**Solution**

Instead, do the following:

```
input_field = browser.find_element(:xpath, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/input')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("disabled");', input_field)
```

Note that:

1. We can locate the element using selenium-webdriver and then pass that element for use in `execute_script` (as the `arguments[0]`).
2. To make a field no longer disabled, you actually need to remove the disabled attribute (rather than setting its value to false).
3. You should be careful with using such an explicit xpath as it can be quite brittle - eg one small change will break it.

Comment: Thanks! @Justin Ko It worked. But the next problem is, it did not enter value as expected into the text field when I appended send_keys after the above lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code is independent of binding language, try below

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementByID('name').value = arguments[0]","John");
```