# javascript executor in rspec automation

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, rspec

I have tried this:

`@browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_element)`

I took help from here:

- [Enabling a disabled field using javascript executor for selenium webdriver ruby binding script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117839/enabling-a-disabled-field-using-javascript-executor-for-selenium-webdriver-ruby)
- [How to execute Javascript in Ruby written Webdriver test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565562/how-to-execute-javascript-in-ruby-written-webdriver-test)

but it is giving error:

```
   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

Comment: Seems like it means that `arguments[0]` doesnt have `click` function.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information about what you are actually trying to achieve here?